# How do I inject dependencies into an iOS view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, inversion-of-control

My view controllers need to send messages to a couple of model objects. How do I obtain references to these model objects inside the view controller?

These model objects are "singletons" (in that there should only be one copy of them in the system at once) and they are used by multiple view controllers. So I can't instantiate them in the init method of each view controller.

I can't use constructor injection as the runtime chooses the init method that gets used to create the view controller.

I can't use "setter injection" as at no point (that I am aware of) do I have both a reference to the newly constructed view controller and references to the "singleton" model objects.

I don't *want* to turn the model objects into proper singletons and call a static method on them from the view controllers to retrieve the singleton instance, as this is a problem for testability. (Having the model objects as properties on the AppDelegate is essentially the same as doing this.)

I am using iOS 6 with Storyboards.

Comment: How did you create your singleton pattern? If you followed Apple examples then you can retrieve the shared instance at any time without creating a new instance.

Comment: I know how to create a singleton and I know it works, but it's bad for testability as you can't inject a mock in place of the real object during testing.

Comment: Why won't setter injection work, by providing the singleton models?

Comment: From where? What place do I have both a reference to the singleton models and a reference to the view controller (that has been instantiated by the runtime when the app starts)?

Comment: This is one reason why I never got myself to like Storyboards...

Comment: It’s sad that four years later we still have no sane official way to pass data between view controllers in a storyboard. The `prepareForSegue:` crutch is pure brain damage.

Answer (score 8):

I've just dealt with the same problem. Since I'm using storyboards I don't instantiate my `UIViewControllers`, so I can't use "constructor injection". I must resign myself using setter injection.

My app root is a `UITabViewController`. Let's say it has two `UINavigationController`s, having the first a `AControllerView` and the second `BControllerView`. In `AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you can retrieve the root controller this way:

`UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;`

Then you can iterate through the controllers:

```
NSArray* viewControllers = [tabBarController viewControllers];
for (UIViewController *viewController in viewControllers) {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*) viewController;
    UIViewController *viewController = navigationController.topViewController;
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass: [AControllerView class]]) {
        AControllerView *a = (AControllerView*) viewController;
        // Inject your stuff
    }
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass: [BControllerView class]]) {
        BControllerView *b = (BControllerView*) viewController;
        // Inject your stuff
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: We'll call this the "bodge up a custom IOC container" approach. If you're going this route you'll soon get to where you may as well use one of the Spring-inspired Objective-C IOC containers on GitHub. I'm interested in feedback on how long it takes you to get there.

Comment: Well, I'm mostly a Java developer and I want to learn Objective C and iOS the right way, I don't want to program iOS the same way I do with other languages! Is there a better way to pass Core Data context around? It certainly reminds me Hibernate Entity Manager injection.

Comment: That wasn't a criticism! I'm in the same situation as you; it seems that IOC isn't a "thing" in Obj-C, to such an extent that whenever I ask an Obj-C developer about how they accomplish what IOC does for Java devs, it feels like we're talking at crossed purposes.

Comment: Ey, I didn't want to react as it were a criticism :). Just a disclaimer. Some friends of mine have joked about that "Java developer way", but I'm in the same situation you describe. This is not a matter of "I miss Seam/Spring". I miss decoupling and testability :/. Somehow I feel a IoC framework is not what I need here, but the alternative feels strange too, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Why not use `NSNotificationCenter`?

> An NSNotificationCenter object (or simply, notification center) provides a mechanism for broadcasting information within a program. An NSNotificationCenter object is essentially a notification dispatch table.

You can add notification observer at both singleton or common one, and when you need to send messages, just post the right notification. Observers'll manage the action then.

[More detail on NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: It's not a broadcast "notification" the view controller wants to send, it's a method call with a return value, so I wouldn't have thought an observer would be appropriate.

Comment: @RobertAtkins "_Broadcasting_" is just a choice, you can add observer to a special one, one-to-one is okay, and what's more, you can return the value by it either. It's very convenient.

Comment: Could you add an example how a VC that needs a model would get a reference to it? If your solution means observing one notification for each model object, it looks quite complex.

Comment: @zoul do u mean `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:<#(nonnull NSString *)#> object:<#(nullable id)#> userInfo:<#(nullable NSDictionary *)#>`? two options: 1. u can send the model instance as object, 2. or store it as dictionary into userInfo if u've a complex structure to notifier the observer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The thing is, with traditional setter or constructor injection there’s zero overhead in the VC that needs some dependency. It simply exposes a constructor parameter or a setter for the dependency and receives it from outside, period. With the notification center solution, it would have to subscribe to a notification for each dependency? That feels quite overkill.

Comment: @zoul right, but not only u can choose to receive all notification w/ the name, but also choose to receive just a special target's notification, while u adding observer by `- (void)addObserver:(id)observer selector:(SEL)aSelector name:(nullable NSString *)aName object:(nullable id)anObject;`, u can set the target to observe, as the doc said _"The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer."_ it's somehow like delegate then, but more independence. :)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this about getting the reference to the view controller object? If you are using storyboards, then the windows `rootViewController` or the segues used will give you the right view controller object.

i.e:
Instance of the view controller when the app starts is

`self.window.rootViewController`

When you are segues to transition between scenes (view controllers):

`[segue destinationViewController]` or `[segue sourceViewController]`

If you are using xibs you could even use an external object(proxy object) from the interface builder to supply the model object. Only thing is you will have to take the nib instantiation into your own hands.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally at some point third party devs will be allowed to use their own constructors/initializers even when using storyboards.

Until then you could use setter/property injection and the mediator pattern, especially since you're used to best practices and loose coupling.

I've written about it here: http://cocoapatterns.com/passing-data-between-view-controllers/

Comment: In your example on the linked page, I'm not sure how ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB get a reference to your mediator object? Does the mediator have a sharedInstance class method to return its singleton? If that's the case I feel it's an incremental improvement (over the VCs managing references to each resource themselves) but I don't think it definitively solves the problem—and indeed it introduces some unnecessary coupling, when the mediator gives access to properties that one VC needs but the other doesn't.

Comment: @RoberAtkins All VCs hold a reference to the mediator which is injected to them by the mediator itself as part of segues. The initial VC gets the mediator from the Composition Root (in the case of iOS the AppDelegate or wherever it is you create your object graph).This can be imposed in a cleaner way by a protocol (named Transitionable for example) all VCs conform to. The mediator can alternatively be a singleton if you prefer so. I personally don't, though I can see why one would argue for it in this use case.

Comment: Also, it may introduce some unnecessary coupling as you say, but it also helps keep the overall coupling low, especially when compared to the "every man for himself" approach which can lead to coupling explosion very easily. Of course the benefits of the pattern shine on bigger projects,  the introduction of the pattern/overhead would obviously be an overkill for a 2-4 scene app. The main advantage though is definitely that it helps with maintenance and substitution of VCs by restricting the changes that need to be done during segues to one place, the mediator.