# How can I prevent ViewControllers from being deallocated after I inject them with a dependency in application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am trying to inject a dependency (to a data store) into all the viewControllers in my tabbed app, from AppDelegate, rather than access the datastore by reaching back into the appDelegate. I am using a storyboard.

I do this in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, and the code executes without errors.

However, when any of the viewControllers is presented, the property into which I have injected the datastore contains nil. I was expecting it to have a reference to the datastore.

I thought maybe my datastore went out of scope after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions returns and caused the datastore to become nil. But to my knowledge ARC should prevent that.

I started to suspect that maybe the VCs might go out of existence after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: finishes running. So I added a dealloc method to the view controllers to see if it gets called, and lo-and-behold, it did. That explains why the dependency I injected previously is no longer there.

Now I am stuck, as I don't know how else to inject the dependency into the view controllers. The only idea I have left is to add properties to my AppDelegate and use them to retain the view controllers, but that feels a bit dangerous cause I'm now interfering with iOS management of view controllers.

Here is the code in AppDelegate:

```
//AppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end

//AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "InjectedViewController.h"
#import "InjectedDataStore.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) InjectedDataStore *myDataStore;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];


if (!_myDataStore) {
    self.myDataStore = [[InjectedDataStore alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"alloc inited %@", self.myDataStore);
}

UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)initViewController;
    for (InjectedViewController *ivc in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
        ivc.dataStore = self.myDataStore;
        NSLog(@"dataStore injected into ivc: %@", ivc.dataStore);
    }

NSLog(@"application:didFinishLaunching... done");

return YES;
}

@end
```

here is my view controller subclass with the property into which I want to inject:

```
//InjectedViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InjectedDataStore.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface InjectedViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) InjectedDataStore *dataStore;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

InjectedViewController.m is boilerplate and otherwise empty.
InjectedDataStore.m and .h are a boilerplate Cocoa Touch class without any properties or methods.

and here is one of the viewcontrollers - it is embedded in a tab view. (The other view controller for the other tab is identical.

```
//FirstViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#import "InjectedViewController.h"
@interface FirstViewController : InjectedViewController
@end

//FirstViewController.m
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSLog(@"data store for FirstVC: %@", self.dataStore);
}

- (void) dealloc {
NSLog(@"First VC dealloc called");
}
@end
```

and finally, the console output:

```
alloc inited <InjectedDataStore: 0x600001d483a0> 
dataStore injected into ivc: <InjectedDataStore: 0x600001d483a0> 
dataStore injected into ivc: <InjectedDataStore: 0x600001d483a0>
application:didFinishLaunching... done

First VC dealloc called   ///this is what causes the injected element to disappear.
Second VC dealloc called  ///causes the injected element to disappear.

data store for FirstVC: (null) 
data store for SecondVC: (null)
```

(I would eventually implement a protocol, but for now since I am stuck at getting the injection to work I have left that out.)

It seems to me what I have done here is very similar to @juanignaciosi 's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169407/how-do-i-inject-dependencies-into-an-ios-view-controller?rq=1) question:

Appreciate any feedback, I am a relative newbie to iOS.

Comment: We don't know what is happen with yours view controllers after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, look's like by logs that you created new tabs

Comment: From the provided code the described log is possible only when `self.window` is `nil`. So find if you set app delegate window property in the moment when you use it.

Comment: @Asperi I do have a UIWindow property to AppDelegate.h, without it my code would not compile. Will edit to include this.

Comment: @Cy-4AH the tabViewController comes from the storyboard, exactly as generated by Xcode 11.5 when you create a tabbed application. The log message "data store for FirstVC: (null)" appears when a tab is first displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your's window property is `nil`.
Since iOS 13 system is using `window` property from scene delegate.
Just remove scene delegate and `UIApplicationSceneManifest` from plist if you don't need it.

Comment: Excellent, this solved my problem! This is an amazing answer, thank you, it solves how to inject dependencies into VCs!! Now I need to find out more about SceneDelegate if I want to do this with scenes.
In addition to removing UIApplicationSceneManifest entry from Info.plist and deleting the SceneDelegate.h and .m files, I also had to delete the two boilerplate UISceneSession lifecycle methods in AppDelegate.m,     (application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession:options:, and 
    application:didDiscardSceneSessions:). Leaving those in caused the app to hang before displaying anything.

Comment: I tried moving the injection code from AppDelegate.m applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: to SceneDelegate.m in the scene:willConnectToSession:Options: 
That appears to make injection successful also, although I am not sure of the impact if I were to add multiple windows support.

Comment: When doing this in SceneDelegate.m, "Programming IOS 13" by Matt Neuburg emphasizes the need to instantiate a UIWindow in the scene:willConnectToSession: method. Even though things seemed to be working without this, I added it in to my code. So I added the following:  
`UIWindowScene *windowScene = (UIWindowScene *)scene;` and `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithWindowScene:windowScene ];` along with `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` and a check for scene not being nil.